# mdatatable in (metronic theme) child-table remove footer description like (Displaying 1 - 3 of 3 records)

Tags: jquery, metronic

How i can remove the bottom information like (Displaying 1 - 3 of 3 records)
Please see into image.
[Following url click to output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WF5s.png)

Answer (score -1):

pagination: true or false

If data.type is defined as remote. Type of remote datasource can be static or dynamic. For the static datasource you can define static JSON file URL. And for dynamic datasource with pagination, sorting and filtering need to be defined as above sample. url is required, and params object is optional.

or you can Edit with "toolbar" ejem:

```
enter code heretoolbar: {
            pagination: {
                items: {
                    default: {
                        first: 'Primero',
                        prev: 'Anterior',
                        next: 'Siguiente',
                        last: 'Último',
                        more: 'Más páginas',
                        input: 'Número de página',
                        select: 'Seleccionar tamaño de página'
                    },
                    info: 'Viendo {{start}} - {{end}} de {{total}} registros'
                }
            }
        }
```

https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=datatable#docs